# date-fns how to convert a non-standard date string without timezone into another format?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have a string date formatted in the form of dd-MM-yyyy, which I want in the form of yyyyMMdd. I tried using the parseISO function but it says the date is invalid.

```
format(parseISO(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I make this date valid?